# Duplicate entries in lsblk output

Tags: centos-7

This is my `lsblk` output:

```bash
lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0   500G  0 disk
├─sda1            8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot
├─sda2            8:2    0   199G  0 part
│ ├─centos-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
│ ├─centos-swap 253:1    0   7.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
│ └─centos-home 253:2    0 441.1G  0 lvm  /home
└─sda3            8:3    0   300G  0 part
  └─centos-home 253:2    0 441.1G  0 lvm  /home
sr0              11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

As you can see that I have 2 `centos-home` entries, 1st one under `sda2` and the 2nd under `sda3`.

**How does that happen? Why?**

*EDIT: This is my fdisk -l output:*

```bash
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 536.9 GB, 536870912000 bytes, 1048576000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000c9dc4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200   419430399   208665600   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda3       419430400  1048575999   314572800   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 8455 MB, 8455716864 bytes, 16515072 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-home: 473.6 GB, 473645973504 bytes, 925089792 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: Why can't you have partitions with same name on different disks?

Comment: An effect of using LVM, I presume? https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/configuring_and_managing_logical_volumes/overview-of-logical-volume-management_configuring-and-managing-logical-volumes

Comment: @harrymc They are actually the same partition mounted to same directory.

Comment: One is under `sda2` and the other under `sda3`. If they are the same partition, then might it be mounted again?